# C言語の文字列の並び替えについて

Tags: c

下記の問題に対して、ファイルを出力する所までは出来たのですが、並び替えの方法が分からず詰まってしまいました。
どなたか教えて頂けないでしょうか？

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i, n;
    int sin[9][6];
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("before_sort2.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        fscanf(fp,"%s", &(sin[i]));
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", sin[i]);
    }
}
```

0. 前提条件
   アルファベットがランダムに記載されたテキストファイル before_sort.txt を手入力で作成する

例）

```
AAA
CCC
BBB
III
DDD
HHH
FFF
EEE
GGG
```

1. 作成した before_sort.txt をプログラムで読み込む
2. コマンドラインからパラメータを受け取り、数字を昇順/降順に並べ替える

例） ASC　を入力

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG
HHH
III
```

例） DESC　を入力

```
III
HHH
GGG
FFF
EEE
DDD
CCC
BBB
AAA
```

★ポイント01　「文字」と「文字列」の違いを意識すること
　　　　　　　今回は「文字列」を複数個（複数行）格納する必要がある
★ポイント02　1bit、1byteとはどのような単位か
　　　　　　　プログラムでよく使うint型やchar型は何byteか
　　　　　　　自分の開発環境ではどうなっているかsizeof関数で確認すること

Comment: 直接並び替えについて尋ねるのではなく、まずはポイント01/02で書かれている助言に従って関連する内容を検索して調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score -2, accepted):

SO 的には「回答」があるほうが良いと思うので、題意を故意に満たしていない回答を提示

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char data[9][6]={
    "YZ.",
    "DEF",
    "PQR",
    "STU",
    "MNO",
    "ABC",
    "VWX",
    "GHI",
    "JKL",
};
    
void printdata() {
    for (int i=0; i<9; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int descending_compare(const void* lh, const void* rh) {
    return -strcmp(lh, rh);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printdata();
    qsort(data, 9, 6, strcmp);
    printdata();
    qsort(data, 9, 6, descending_compare);
    printdata();
}
```

オイラからの課題１．実際にコンパイルして実行してみること
課題２．なぜこれで文字列のソートになるのか理解し SO 読者に解説すること
課題３．このコードには直したほうが良い点がいくつか故意に含まれているので、修正してみること